# OpenSSL CLI - Including password in Command

Tags: encryption, openssl

Is it possible to encrypt a file without OpenSSL asking for a password?
Can I include the Password in the command?

```
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -in secrets.txt -out secrets.enc
enter AES-256-CBC encryption password:
```

I'm guessing something like **--key testkey**

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/724986/how-to-use-password-argument-in-via-command-line-to-openssl-for-decryption

Comment: @MatsK, Thank you so much. Solved!